# Java regex not working for the input string in the second line

Tags: java, regex

I have the below code which works perfectly when I pass these parameters from   the    console.

Test-case

```
{"012.99 008.73","099.99 050.00","123.45 101.07"}
```

Source code

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.println("Pass the parameters");
String line=br.readLine();
String str=line.replaceAll("[^0-9 A-Z a-z /, .]","");
String[] nos=str.split(",");

for(String s:nos){
    System.out.print(s+"\t");
}
```

But the above code does not work when i pass the below parameters from the   console.

```
{"612.72 941.34","576.46 182.66","787.41 524.70","637.96 333.23","345.01 219.69",
 "567.22 104.77","673.02 885.77"}
```

The String array nos is missing out the strings "567.22 104.77","673.02 885.77" in the second line.

Please help me on this.

Comment: The rest of the input is in the second line.. You are just reading one line

Comment: `String tmp, line = "" ; while ((tmp=br.readLine())!=null) line+=tmp;` should do it for you instead of the third line of your code.

Answer (score 1):

It is not working because you are reading only first line.

Here, You need to read all line in a string. Then use regex on it.

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.println("Pass the parameters");
String line;

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
}
line = sb.toString();

String str=line.replaceAll("[^0-9 A-Z a-z /, .]","");
String[] nos=str.split(",");

for(String s:nos){
    System.out.print(s+"\t");
}
```